# JSON.Net deserialization populate missing properties

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I want to deserialize a json object into a c# class and have a completely populated default object even if my JSON is missing the information. I've tried

- Annotation with [DefaultValue]
- Creating constructors for the classes
- Deserializing with a settings object

Settings object:

```
new JsonSerializerSettings {
    DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Populate
    NulValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include
    ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Replace
}
```

Consider these c# classes

```
public class Root{
    public SpecialProperty name {get;set;}
    public SpecialProperty surname {get;set;}
}

public class SpecialProperty {
    string type {get;set;}
    string value {get;set;}
}
```

Consider this JSON

```
"Root" : {
    "name" : { 
        "type" : "string",
        "value": "MyFirstname"
    }
}
```

How can I deserialize this json into an object with the available data serialized into a new object and the missing properties, in this case, set to `string.empty`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest workaround is putting the default value you want in the constructor.

```
public class Root
{
    public SpecialProperty Name { get; set; }
    public SpecialProperty Surname { get; set; }

    public Root()
    {
        this.Name = SpecialProperty.GetEmptyInstance();
        this.Surname = SpecialProperty.GetEmptyInstance();
    }
}

public class SpecialProperty
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }

    public static SpecialProperty GetEmptyInstance()
    {
         return new SpecialProperty
         {
              Name = string.Empty,
              Type = string.Empty
         };
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I went with. Created contstructors and initialising them everywhere. Though I still think it should be able to initialise the whole thing by annotations and the `JsonSerializerSettings` object but maybe the word `Serializer` is paramount in this story because I am trying to deserialize. If anyone discovers a pure JsonNet solution without having to go through classes creating and newing up objects I'd like to know.

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to deserialize into object X, store your defaults into object Y and then use something like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) to map the non-null values from X to Y.